# Docker Desktop on Windows 10 not running

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

Im trying to get Docker Desktop to run on my Windows 10 pc but its stuck on stop. I tried uninstalling and deleting all traces of docker in the folders below and then reinstalling it and running & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon in powershell but no luck.

```
C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
C:\Users\ProgramData\Docker
C:\Users\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
```

Any ideas how to get Docker Desktop to run?

```
Docker Desktop 4.26.1
Docker version 24.0.7 
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally solved my issue. There seems to be an issue with 4.26.1 because a lot of people seem to have the same error. The workaround was to uninstall Docker Desktop and reinstall an older version 4.22.0. I had also uninstalled WSL2 and reinstalled it with Docker Desktop.